# Confusion about ionised atom, free electron, conduction band, donor energy level and acceptor energy level

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, orbitals

I have some confusion about the concept of some electronic bands and energy levels. Beyond valance band,

For an atom, can having at least one electron in the conduction band mean that the atom has been ionised?

Can having an electron in the donor energy level or acceptor energy level mean that the atom has been ionised?

Is free electron same as an electron in the conduction band or an electron in the acceptor or donor band?

Is an atom having a free electron an ionised atom?

I am super-super-confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [band theory of solids](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html) has developed to describe the collective behavior of atoms and molecules when in the solid form.

[image: bands]

The confusion goes away if one realizes that different quantum mechanical models have developed in order to describe different problems.

> For an atom, can having at least one electron in the conduction band mean that the atom has been ionised?

In order for an electron to be considered in the conduction band, one needs a solid. Individual atoms/molecules sit at the lattice sites of the solid. The model is that the conduction band has electrons that are bound  over the whole lattice. The valence band electrons are tied on the points of the lattice where the nucleus also sits (depending on the material, whether insulator or conductor).

In the sense of the band theory model, the whole lattice is still neutral. Just the conduction band electrons have definition  over the whole lattice ( a quantum mechanical probability to be anywhere in the lattice). It has little meaning to talk about an ionized atom, because its "*own* electron might be away but another in the conduction band is near", (as a hand-waving explanation).

> Can having an electron in the donor energy level or acceptor energy level mean that the atom has been ionised?

If for individual atoms, yes, but if the atom is part of a lattice see above.

> Is free electron same as an electron in the conduction band or an electron in the acceptor or donor band?

No a free electron means there is no potential that is binding it.

> Is an atom having a free electron an ionized atom?

If the atom is not in a lattice and it  attracts a floating electron, yes it will be a negatively ionize atom. If in a lattice,see above

Maybe if you read the whole link your confusion will go away.

Comment: So, a free electron is sourced from a positively ionized atom? And a free electron does not have any connection to any energy and band levels since there is no electrical potential binding it??

Comment: yes, that's what free means. An electron in a solid is never "free", it is in an energy level of the lattice ,instead of just an atom.

Comment: Is it correct to say: "For a single atom any energy above valance energy level is free electron, but for a solid lattice, anything above conduction level is free electron aka positively ionized(loss of electron by freeing it with absorption of required energy) atom then? @anna v

Comment: No. You are confusing in the statement the two models, the standard atomic model with the electrons energy levels according to the potential between the lectrons and the nucleus,  and the term "valence" has no meaning in this model, the term "free electron" has. and the band theory of solids with a collective potential for a large number of atoms at lattice points tied by chemical bonds when looked at individually, but fitting collectively the band theory QM model. Here belongs the "valence" and not the "fee electron".

Comment: Hand waving you can call the electrons in the conduction band "free" to wander the whole lattice, and in conductors even the valence quarks can be described by handwaving as able to move through the lattice (see link), they are all not free to various degrees but at lattice energy levels.

Comment: Thank you, so, some say "A Free Electron = A Mobile Charge" if we use this equality, I mean if we refer to "mobile charges" in the lattice by saying "free electrons" then everything fits in right? Then It becomes "a mobile charge  = an electron in the conduction band = free electron", right??

Comment: yes, but it does lead to confusing what "free" means, a different definition.

Comment: @annav your second comment "**An electron in a solid is never "free", it is in an energy level of the lattice**" I think that is not only free electrons but every electron inside a lattice is under the influence of all the electrons and nucleus present inside so every electron present in that lattice will get affected with this thing and of course the energy, so what makes the conduction band and valance band different from eachother (neglecting the difference that the free electrons are free to move or obviously outside the atom and the electrons in valance band are always inside the atom).

Comment: @TejasDahake In the band model, as in all quantum mechanical models, electrons fill the energy levels sequentially, in the order of "lower are filled up first". So it depends on the atoms participating in  the solid  and how many electrons make them neutral. In the solid model if there are electrons in the conduction band, then these are very good conductors. The valence band electrons although filling up energy levels of the whole lattice, are not able to move to the conduction band. In a *microscopic view*, the conduction band electrons are tied up in the lattice positions of atoms,

Comment: whereas the conduction band ones are not. see this for the microscopic view of current http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Answer (score 1):

[Ionization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization) requires an atom/molecule as a whole, should have a net positive charge i.e. an electron has to be completely removed from the neutral atom/molecule. Strictly speaking, addition of electrons to a neutral atom is also a kind of ionization (and hence the name [AN'ION'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion#Anions_and_cations)) and so the most general definition nessesitates the requirement of a NET CHARGE on the atom/molecule.

In all the occasions you have mentioned the atom/molecule is neutral, hence not ionized. To be more precise, ionization is a extreme [Excitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excited_state#Atomic_excitation) when the [excitation energy](https://www.britannica.com/science/excitation-energy) equal (or greater than) [Ionization Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy) of that state.

Now all the situations you have mentioned are either ground state or excited states but not Ionized state.

---

Usage of the term "Free Electrons" -

1. Free electrons/particles occur when there is no BOUND POTENTIAL in the Hamiltonian. It is commonly characterized by a infinitely whole range energy levels with no forbidden states poking around.
2. Misnomer in Solid State Physics - Any solution of Schrodinger Equation that represent the Plane Wave solution is commonly called as Free Electron. It is important to note that strictly speaking these are not "free Electron" although they don't explicitly have a Potential in the Hamiltonian, the bound potential is implicitly taken into consideration in the [Effective Mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)). This approach simplifies the calculation, but doesn't change the physics. Hence, electrons in the various bands of the Lattice are in fact bound electrons, although some of them may be referred to as free electrons! Another effect of these bound electrons is that you have to provide some quanta of energy to release it from the lattice.

Comment: Is free electron and electron in conduction band same thing?

Comment: so, both "an electron in the conduction band" and "free electron" sources from an ionised(anion) atom?

Comment: Just to clarify, neither atoms nor molecules have free electrons, but have bound electrons (implying that these electrons are bound to the nuclei). Electron in a conduction band is also a bound electron as it is not free to leave as it pleases, there is an energy requirement usually called as Work Function involved in taking out a conduction band electron.

Comment: so, "an electron in the conduction band" does not mean that the atom has been ionised, but a free electron means that an atom has been ionised?? But We know that metals are good conductors because of the electrons in the "conduction band = free electrons" !!?

Comment: Conduction bands doesnt mean free electrons. Conduction bands are very similar to the orbitals of an atom (both are bound states of electrons), but now that its a group of special atoms (usually metals) that come together to form a orbitals that have a finite width and hence are called bands. The terms conduction arises because electrons in these bands are usually the once that conducts electricity.

Comment: If the electricity(current) has been occured, then the electrons in the conduction band has to move away from the source atom, that means, the electrons in the conduction band is free electrons, that means they are sourced from an atom that has been ionised because their electrons are now moving away from them in the copper cable ??

Comment: ohh... not exactly. Current (in out context) is a phenomena that occur due to **drift** of electrons and not sourcing of electrons. Batteries doesn't source electrons they simply provide potential so that electrons already present in the wire/conductor can drift across. So, in our context as soon as one electron leaves an a nuclei other electron behind it takes its place, essentially keeping the conductor (and hence the entities that make up the conductor) neutral!

Comment: But we always say that metals conduct electricity since they have free electrons. We do not generally use the phrase "electrons in the conduction band", we always say they have "free electrons". I am confused again... Now you say that free electrons occur with an ionized atom, so if metals have free electrons thus conducting electricity, their atoms all must be ions...How so??

Comment: Ohh yes I should have said that earlier. The electrons in metals are studied using mean field models, the sort of first/naive approximation to it is a model called [Free electron model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model). The model got its name due to fact that the solutions turns out to be exactly similar to free electrons but with an effective mass. It should **NOT** be confused with the fact that electrons in metals are free. As far as I can tell, this particular phrase "free electrons in conduction bands" stuck because of this model.

Comment: So, it is correct to regard "an electron in the conduction band" as "a free electron", however both of them does not refer to "an electron sourced from an ionized atom" ??

Comment: No its wrong to regard an electron in conduction band as a free electron, simply because this is a bound system and so electrons are "bound" and no free to go outside the metal. The particular phrase is a misnomer that got stick in literature probably because of the fame of Free Electron Model.

Comment: Is it correct to say: "For a single atom any energy above valance energy level is free electron, but for a solid lattice, anything above conduction level is free electron aka positively ionized(loss of electron by freeing it with absorption of required energy) atom then? @TheImperfectCrazy

Comment: "A Free Electron = A Mobile Charge" if we use this equality, I mean if we refer to "mobile charges" in the lattice by saying "free electrons" then everything fits in right? Then It becomes "a mobile charge  = an electron in the conduction band = free electron", right??

Comment: Ahh... Mobile electrons are a much better word to use. It would to correct to say that "electrons in conduction band are mobile electron." All electrons above valence band need not be mobile electrons. I cant think of any example right now, but in general you can have certain bands above conduction band that need not be conduction bands. This commonly happens when you have a very large energy gap above the conduction band especially due to topological effects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126495/discussion-between-theimperfectcrazy-and-physicssolvesall).